# How do you cache a nextjs page that has getServerSideProps?

Tags: next.js, http-caching

pages/stuff.ts

```
export function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const userId = getUserIdOrNull(context);
  return {props: { somethingComplicated: getSomethingComplicated(!!userId) }};
}
export default Home({somethingComplicated}) {
  return <div>{somethingComplicated}</div>
}
```

How do you cache this page?!

Ideally I'd like to cache the page `<Home {...{somethingComplicated}}/>` based on the different contexts.

Possible but unsatisfying solutions:

- Cache the calculation of `somethingComplicated`. Unsatisfying because Home would need to be recalculated every time and cannot be cached by cloudflare.
- Load somethingComplicated dynamically on the client from an api.  Unsatisfying because the lack of server side rendering is a worse user experience.
- Route for logged in users and logged out users to different routes. Unsatisfying because user visible urls will be different and the redirects get complicated.

I can't seem to find a satisfying solution. Maybe it's not possible? Anyways, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This might help: https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching

Comment: @skndstry that just lets me set the cache header, not actually cache anything right? All the caching would depend on cloudflare.

Answer (score 2):

> By default, Next.js pre-renders every page. This means that Next.js
> generates HTML for each page in advance, instead of having it all done
> by client-side JavaScript. Pre-rendering can result in better
> performance and SEO.
>
> Each generated HTML is associated with minimal JavaScript code
> necessary for that page. When a page is loaded by the browser, its
> JavaScript code runs and makes the page fully interactive. (This
> process is called hydration.)
>
> ### Two forms of Pre-rendering:

> Next.js has two forms of pre-rendering:
> Static Generation and Server-side Rendering. The difference is in when
> it generates the HTML for a page.
>
> Static Generation (Recommended): The HTML is generated at build time
> and will be reused on each request. Server-side Rendering: The HTML is
> generated on each request.

[you can read more](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)

If you are using `getServerSideProps` that means every time a user visits that page, you want to fetch fresh data and serve it to the user. If your serverside is doing heavy calculation or hitting database disk you could implement caching layer between application server and db or other servers. You could use [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In express I could cache the html I send per user, you are saying I can only cache the props I send to the page right?

Comment: the link that I shared, if you scroll down, you can see static page generation. next.js caches those pages. you have another option, bu statically build and then after certatin time, you refetch data behind the scene and update the cache. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: but caching the page with getServerSideProps will defeat the purpose of using `getServerSideProps`

Comment: How does it defeat the point? In my example above I display two different possibilities: logged in html or logged out html. Rendering the react component could be expensive so I want to cache the rendered html for those two possibilities.

Comment: @evandwight with getServerSideProps, everytime a user visits your page, you have to some calculation inside getServerSideProps. so your html has to wait for this server side calculation. how are you going to cache this and serve the cached data. i think the think you want  `incremental-static-regeneration`.

Comment: Static generation only provides one version of page. I want a single route to have two versions - logged in and logged out. The only calculation I want to do on the server is are you logged in or logged out. Once I've done that calculation I want to send the cached html for that version. This is possible in express, but I don't think it's possible in nextjs.